# display a file on page using php

Tags: php, file, search-engine, displayobject

I made a script that searches in a category for a file. My issue is: after searching the script doesn't display results of the search. Example: I'm searching for a game like :-? AC3. After search the script doesn't display any result. Some help?

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<font color="black" size="4">
<?php
//define each directory here, the index starts with 0 == all and so on.
$categorydir = array('/Category/All/', '/Category/PCGames/', '/Category/Console/', '/Category/Movies/', '/Category/Music/', '/Category/XXX/', '/Category/Windows/', '/Category/Linux/', '/Category/Software/', '/Category/Documents/');
//if option selected and its valid number
if (isset($_POST['category']))
 if(ctype_digit($_POST['category']) && isset($categorydir[$_POST['category']]))
if(array_key_exists($_POST['category'], $categorydir) && is_dir($categorydir[$_POST['category']])){
is_dir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]);
  $files = scandir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]);
  echo 'target directory not found';
echo 'Results of search:<br></br>';
foreach($files as $file){
  echo($file);
}
?>
</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DataHunters</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">DataHunters</a>
</h1>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</li></a>
<li><a href="chat.html">Chat</li></a>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</li></a>
<li><a href="http://www.forum.datahunters.ro">Forum</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I`m expecting at a script who post the results after search.

Comment: What are you expecting for the results? You aren't outputting anything in the code above except for "target directory not found" and "Results of search:"

Comment: It is very hard to read your code. Use more braces.

Comment: So, man look here. All I want is a script who browse in categaory for a file and then display the file. The script what I made have some bugs and I`m expecting at you or anyone else remove that bugs.(Sorry for the bad english)

Comment: Browse for a **what** file?

Comment: Also there is a senseless using `array_key_exists($_POST['category']` after `isset($categorydir[$_POST['category']])`. These conditions are almost the same.

Comment: Any file. example: User X is searching in PCgames for Y game another user is searching in Movies for Z movie...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're opening a directory and not doing anything with the handle. You might instead try using scandir() which will result in an array of the files in the directory, instead of a directory object.

Edit: you might try something like this:

```
...
is_dir($categorydir[$_POST['category']])){
  $files = scandir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]);
}else{
  echo 'target directory not found';
}
echo 'Results of search:<br></br>';
foreach($files as $file){
  echo($file);
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `$handle = opendir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]);` with `print_r(scandir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]));` and see if that gives you a push in the right direction.

Comment: In the right is "Results of search:" but no file for I was searching

Comment: Did you get a list of the files in the directory printed out from print_r()? If so, instead of using print_r(), store the result of scandir() into an array. In the place of your echo(), use a foreach() loop to go through the array and print the file name.

Comment: I don`t know so much PHP this script I had made with some help. :|. A list with what? The name of all files in the directory?

Comment: print_r() is a PHP command to print an Array. You should have seen somewhere in your resulting HTML where that line executed a list of the files in your directory, indicating that scandir() was successfully finding and reading the contents of the target.

Comment: If I say I don`t understand anything you belive me?

Comment: [sigh] Yes, I do believe you. You really should probably take a step back and learn some PHP basics first, like variables, arrays, and loops. I added some stuff to the original comment.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: files in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Remember that all variables need to start with a $. Please see the updated comment.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 44 ->See the update on my topic

Comment: You removed one of the if() statements.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: category in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 14...And now?

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 14

Warning: scandir(): Directory name cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 14
target directory not foundResults of search:


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 17

Comment: One of the variables is undefined. I'm sorry, but you really need to gain at least some basic knowledge of PHP, or it sounds like even programming in general at this point. If I get a chance later, I'll post a complete example. For the future, if you didn't write something yourself "I made a script...", don't say you did. Really, your question is "I was given this script and it doesn't work, can you fix it?". Until I can update my post later, look up a tutorial on beginning PHP, and try to become at least a little familiar with the language and what different errors mean.